# PDF reader that remembers page across devices

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, reading

When I'm reading some material on my desktop and want to bring it with me on either my tablet or my laptop, I will have to remember at what page I was, to continue reading. That does not work me.

Does there exist a PDF reader that syncs the page view across devices?
Preferably across computers, tablets, and smartphones - but simply across computers would be a hugely appreciated.